# Mean of list of unaqual lists

Tags: python, list, mean

I try to get a list that include the mean of all of (i)th element in all lists of a list.To explain more, if i have the next list:

```
A=[[1,2],  [2,3], [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [2,2,1]].
```

I want to have `[a,b,c]` with:

```
a = (1+2+1+3+2)/5
b = (2+3+2+4+2)/5
c = (3+5+1)/3
```

Any help please!

Comment: funny how all proposed solutions are the same XD

Answer (score 2):

use `itertools.zip_longest` to zip values together. The extra difficulty is that the length of the data varies. `zip_longest` inserts `None` as a fill value. We have to create a filtered list, and count only those items:

```
import itertools

A=[[1,2], [2,3], [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [2,2,1]]

tuples = itertools.zip_longest(*A)
for t in tuples:
    s = [x for x in t if x is not None]
    print(sum(s)/len(s))
```

result:

```
1.8
2.6
3.0
```

EDIT: one-liner (maybe a bit more complex, using `lambda` to compute mean):

```
result = [(lambda x : sum(x)/len(x))([x for x in t if x is not None]) for t in itertools.zip_longest(*A)]
```

result: `[1.8, 2.6, 3.0]`

(Python 2 users have to replace `zip_longest` by `izip_longest`)

Comment: PS: zip_longest not supported anymore, changed to izip_longest

Comment: @E.Em: actually it's the opposite. You're using python 2. You can accept the answer if it works BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) like so if you are on Python2:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
from __future__ import division

A=[[1,2],  [2,3], [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [2,2,1]]
a,b,c = [sum(filter(None, c))/len(filter(None,c)) for c in izip_longest(*A)]

print a
print b
print c
```

Output:

```
1.8
2.6
3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to generate the sublists, and [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to calculate the average for each group, disregarding the `None`s:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from statistics import mean

averages = list(map(lambda l: mean(i for i in l if i != None), zip_longest(*A)))
```

With your example:

```
>>> A = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [2, 2, 1]]
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> list(map(lambda l: mean(i for i in l if i != None), zip_longest(*A)))
[1.8, 2.6, 3]
```

Comment: you can also use a list comprehension instead of a list-map-lambda: `[ mean(i for i in L if i !=None) for L in zip_longest(*A) ]` and is shorted

Comment: Statistics is deprecated, changed to scipy.stats

Comment: I got this error  TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: @E.Em `statistics` is a python builtin module, definitely not deprecated, `scipy` is an external package. Also, my code contains no trace of `len` so your error is probably from one of the other answers.

Comment: at first I thought that it was some external module that I happens to have because it come with anaconda, but no, it is a build-in indeed, I spotted it while searching for something else and I returned here immediately to give you my up-vote XD, I also include the link to it

Comment: but there is a problem, is a build-in only since 3.4 and is not available in older versions like 2.7

Comment: Yes it is not available in python 2.7.. you have to down-vote now..  ;)